# What does it mean if a JS function works in the console but not in a document.ready(...)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery call that I'm using to disable a functionality of a Wordpress plugin for my website. It is

```
$('.vc_gitem-animated-block a').unbind('click');
```

and it works when I paste it in the console after the page loads. However, it does not work when I paste

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.vc_gitem-animated-block a').unbind('click');
});
```

So I assume my `unbind` function was getting fired before the function that binds the event in the first place. I therefore did

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.vc_gitem-animated-block a').unbind('click');
    }, 1000);
});
```

and now it works. However, I want a better solution for the production site, since that solutions seems a little sketchy. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: That completely depends on where / how it's being bound.

Comment: Question, why are you binding in the first place if your then going to unbind?  Out of curiosity.

Comment: document.ready functions are the first callbacks being run after the scripts are loaded. Might it not be easier to remove the element from your dom instead?

Comment: Looks like a quick bandaid, in which case a setTimeout would be acceptable, since that's just as much of a code smell as unbinding an arbitrary event rather than just not binding it in the first place.

Comment: are you sure this class "vc_gitem-animated-block" is already there in your HTML or it is also being added dynamically by some other script/framework. Obviously when document.ready is called this class is not there which means you need to figure out which part of your code/library is adding this class and accordingly sequence your call.